# SVN post-commit user permissions

Tags: debian, svn

I've a debian webserver with subversion running on it.

I'm trying to use post-commit script to update my staging version of my site.

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/svn update /home/sites/example.com/www >> /var/log/svn/example.log 2>&1
```

if I run that command from the command line logged in as user 'derek' then it all works fine

but when it runs as post-commit I get the following error in my log file:

```
svn: Can't open file '/home/sites/example.com/www/.svn/lock': Permission denied
```

Ok, so I realize what is happening here is the user calling the post-commit script isn't 'derek' so it hasn't permission.

So my question is what user is calling the post-commit script.

the svnserve daemon is run as derek ... I thought that would mean the post-commit command would be called as derek too but it seems not.

Any ideas how I can find out what user is calling it

and secondly what would be the best practice method to allow access for that user?  I don't think adding it to the group would help because the group doesn't have the write access to the .svn directories by default.

UPDATE:
I've just found that www-data is the user that seems to be calling the script. Now naturally www-data can't run the svn command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.  I had to write my own c program but it works!

thanks to info I found here:
http://forum.webfaction.com/viewtopic.php?pid=216#p216

Answer (score 1):

`who am i >> /var/log/svn/example.log` will output under which user the command is running.

Comment: nice idea. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. The hooks are run as the user svnserve is running as.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks

> Subversion executes hooks as the same
>   user who owns the process that is
>   accessing the Subversion repository.
>   In most cases, the repository is being
>   accessed via a Subversion server, so
>   this user is the same user as whom the
>   server runs on the system

Comment: thats what I thought but for some reason i'm still getting the error.

Comment: its seems it's www-data..

Comment: if it's running as www-data, it looks like you're serving the repo through apache, not svnserve